# How do I get Susie as a pardner?

Tags: west-of-loathing

How do I get Susie as a pardner? I wanted to know badly.
 I can't seem to find the rifle. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Dragonrage that question is about unlocking pardners except for Susie and Crazy Pete.

Comment: IMO this should remain closed, and the other question should get a new answer that discusses this,

Answer (score 3):

The rifle can be found at the Cochrane's Ranch inside of a dilapidated building.  When you enter the building, you'll be in dark basement.  At the end of the basement is a gun safe.  Inside the safe is the rifle.  Give the rifle to Susie, and she will offer to follow you.

Source: A [Markiplier Video](https://youtu.be/YHQ5uHrjfoc?t=21m17s) of the game.